# Polyhedron with 12 pentagons and 1 hexagon

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra

In this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/19823/5239, it is indicated that it is impossible to make a polyhedron (with 3 faces meeting at each vertex) out of 12 pentagons and 1 hexagon.

There is certainly an easy reason why one hexagon is not possible but I have to admit that I am missing it. (In the reference given, it is stated as 'obvious'). Any help?

Comment: C22 fullerene is impossible. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/wcms.1207/pdf

Answer (score 1):

We can build up such a polyhedron starting from the unqique hexagon:
Each of its edges must be an edge of a pentagon. By the three-faces-per-vertex condition, pentagons touching neighbouring edges must be distinct and share an edge. Even if we consider only the planar graph, not a 3d polyhedron, this makes it impossible that any two of theses six pentagons coincide.
Using the three-faces-per-vertex condition again, there must be a second ring of six pentagons around this. These leave us with six edges than cannot be "closed".

Comment: Yes, I thought about this. But how do you know that the pentagons in the first ring don't share some "external" edges?

Comment: It seems to me that there are a lot of cases to consider. I would have hoped for something more systematic.